# iText 7 Adding colored text and fill to a rectangle

Tags: itext, rect

I am trying to add colored text to a rectangle and fill color in the rectangle but the
text seems to be behind the rectangle and so is not visible even though I can select it.

```
       Paragraph  = new Paragraph("The quick brown fox");
       PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.addNewPage());
       Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(ps.getWidth() - 90, ps.getHeight() - 100, 50, 50);
       new Canvas(canvas, pdfDoc, rect)
            .setFontColor(ColorConstants.WHITE)
            .setFontSize(12)
            .add(p);
       canvas.rectangle(rect)
            .setFillColor(ColorConstants.LIGHT_GRAY)
            .fillStroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first draw the text and then fill the rectangle. Thus, obviously the text ends up *behind the rectangle*.

Switch the order of your instructions, first fill the rectangle `rect` on your `PdfCanvas canvas` and then add the `Paragraph p` to the `Canvas` on `canvas.`

Comment: Great that it helped!