# iText8 Canvas class is not rendering text to the report

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

Working with the Java version of iText 8, I used to have the following line of code to render text into a page of my report: `document.showTextAligned(p, llx, lly, this.page, txtAlignment, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE,0);`
where p is of type Paragraph, this.page is of type int and txtAlignment is of type TextAlignment.

Now, I have changed it for this:

```
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(pdfPage);
try (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, rect, true)) {
    canvas.add(p);
}
```

The reason for this is so that I can fit text inside a rectangle but the problem is that this code fails to render any text into my report, the page is just blank. What could the reason be? The code is pretty much copy-paste from [this entry from two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443713/itext-7-adding-colored-text-and-fill-to-a-rectangle).

I have already checked all obvious possible causes. The Rectangle rect is within the borders of the page, pdfPage is a valid page of the report (it's in fact, the current page i'm writing to) and no exceptions occur during the exectution of the method.

Comment: *"The code is pretty much copy-paste from this entry from two years ago."* - you are aware that that question was about text not being visible? So if you copied&pasted that code, text is likely to be invisible...

Comment: In that question, text was not visible because a rectangle was being rendered on top of the paragraph. There is no rectangle in my case.

Comment: *"In that question, text was not visible because a rectangle was being rendered on top of the paragraph. There is no rectangle in my case."* - ah, so your case is not *pretty much copy-paste* from that post... then why do you mention it?

Comment: For an analysis please share a PDF edited of your code, both a before and an after copy. From that we can determine whether the paragraph was rendered after all and merely is not visible or whether it really has not been rendered at all.